# exclude file with Glob

Tags: php

I am using glob to get a list of files in a directory.

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/{data-,list-}*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
```

Let say my file list in directory is as follow

```
data-financebyyear.php
data-finance.php
data-hrbyyear.php
```

How do i exclude all the files with byyear in the filename ?

i tried it something like this and its not working ..all files are still displayed

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/{data-,list-}*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
        if (strpos($filename, 'byyear') !== false) {
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
       }
    }
```

Comment: `if (strpos($filename, 'byyear') === false)`

Comment: `!==` means that `byyear` will be present in a filename.

Comment: Thank you very much @u_mulder..got it

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/{data-,list-}*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
        if (strpos($filename, 'byyear') === false) {
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
       }
    }
```